# tornadoweb template variable pipe safe

Tags: javascript, templates, pipe, tornado

In my backend handler I'm sending string with double quots, like:

```
print '\"test\"'
self.render('test.html', test = '\"test\"')
```

in template test.html I'm passing test variable into javascript, like:

```
<script>
var test = {{ test }};
</script>
```

But what actually browser generates is:

```
<script>
var test = &quo t;test&quo t;;
</script>
```

string quote appears instead of double quote "

Is there in tornadoweb something similar to Django pipeline, which should do the trick:

```
<script>
var test = {{ test|safe }};
</script>
```

Or maybe there is another way for passing strings with double quotes (which I really need in frontend)?

greets!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it on my own:

```
{% autoescape None %}
```